# How does the ! operator really works in a Boolean logic?

Tags: javascript

I'm new in Js and i just want to know if my idea of the ! (NOT operator) is right.

e.g

```
const hasDriversLicense = true;
const hasGoodVision = true;
const isTired = false;

if (hasDriversLicense && hasGoodVision && !isTired) {
  console.log("Sarah is able to drive!");
} else {
  console.log("Someone else should drive..");
}
```

in the previous code the condition is that if...

- Sarah has driver's license, and
- if has good vision, and
- is NOT tired

she should be able to drive, okay?

The way I was analyzing this in code was well I have a `hasDriversLicense` var which is `true` so this means that Sarah actually has a drivers license, and in relation of this way of thinking the next condition also make sense, so `hasGoodVision` is `true` so it means it has a good vision.

My confusion comes when we are in this part `!isTired`, right now the `isTired` var is set it to `false` that means that if we relate this with our if condition Sarah is able to drive.

So when we say `!isTired` that means that `isTired` is `false` and then becomes `true` cause of the `!` so this means that actually  Sarah is Tired?  and she is not able to drive

This way of thinking was confusing but I start thinking that the `!` works as a validator not really as a value changer of the complete context. What I mean with this is that we can say that this `!isTired` is like saying *"validate if this var value is actually false in that case return true"*, so it's true that is `false` that's why we get this. Is this a valid way see the behavior of this operator?

want to know if my idea of the ! (NOT operator) is right.

Comment: There's a lot going on here and I'm not sure if any of it makes sense, but it does sound like a trip to [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra) is in order, or at least a crash course on boolean logic.

Comment: Tip: Test in the JavaScript console `!true` and `!false` and `!!true` etc.

Comment: _"this means that actually Sarah is Tired?"_... Simply read `!isTired` as _"not (is) tired"_ and it should make sense

Comment: _"so this means that actually Sarah is Tired?"_ - if `!isTired` is `true` then it means Sarah is not tired.

Answer (score 0):

I think you got it right yea

```
const isTired = false

console.log(!isTired) // output: true
```

"!" means "NOT" in my mind

Like you said it won't change the value but validate and check whether it's, in that case, "not" truthy or "not" falsy